# getting touch ended to use else if statement objective c for shooter game

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

Hello I have a question about some code I am trying to get to allow the user to select different weapon options.  I have an if statement and then an else if statement in the touchesBegan and touchesEnded methods but for some reason in the touchesEnded method, my else if will not function.  The else if in the touchesBegan does as I am telling it to do, but when I try swiping for the touchesEnded for the "3-Way Shot" I get no response, but I can switch back to "Regular Shot" and it works fine.  Is this maybe needing another touch added to it?  I've tried a few different things but nothing is functioning the way I would like it to.  I have not added the two other "missiles" but will not be worried about that until I can get it to actually fire just the regular "missile" when _tripleShot is true.  Also I had set _regularShot to true in the initWithSize method, but was assuming if the touch changed it later it would not always be true.  Does initWithSize keep _regularShot true even if the value is changed in touchesBegan?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    _touchLocation = location;
    _touchTime = CACurrentMediaTime();

    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:_touchLocation];
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"1Shot"])
    {
        _regularShot = NO;
        _tripleShot = NO;
        _regularShot = YES;

        _weaponSelected.text = @"Weapon: Lazer";
        _weaponNumber = 1;

    }

    else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"3Shot"])
    {
        _regularShot = NO;
        _tripleShot = NO;
        _tripleShot = YES;

        _weaponSelected.text = @"Weapon: 3-Way Shot";
        _weaponNumber = 2;

    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

     if (_regularShot) {

    if (CACurrentMediaTime() - _touchTime < 0.3 && _playerMissileSprite1.hidden)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint diff = CGPointMake(location.x - _touchLocation.x, location.y -      _touchLocation.y);
        float diffLength = sqrtf(diff.x*diff.x + diff.y*diff.y);
        if (diffLength > 4.0f)
        {
            float angle = atan2f(diff.y, diff.x);
            _playerMissileSprite1.zRotation = angle - SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.0f);

            _playerMissileSprite1.position = _playerSprite.position;
            _playerMissileSprite1.hidden = NO;

            float adjacent, opposite;
            CGPoint destination;

            if (angle <= -M_PI_4 && angle > -3.0f * M_PI_4)
            {
                // Shoot down
                angle = M_PI_2 - angle;
                adjacent = _playerMissileSprite1.position.y + Margin;
                opposite = tanf(angle) * adjacent;
                destination = CGPointMake(_playerMissileSprite1.position.x - opposite,  -Margin);
            }
            else if (angle > M_PI_4 && angle <= 3.0f * M_PI_4)
            {
                // Shoot up
                angle = M_PI_2 - angle;
                adjacent = _winSize.height - _playerMissileSprite1.position.y + Margin;
                opposite = tanf(angle) * adjacent;
                destination = CGPointMake(_playerMissileSprite1.position.x + opposite, _winSize.height + Margin);
            }
            else if (angle <= M_PI_4 && angle > -M_PI_4)
            {
                // Shoot right
                adjacent = _winSize.width - _playerMissileSprite1.position.x + Margin;
                opposite = tanf(angle) * adjacent;
                destination = CGPointMake(_winSize.width + Margin, _playerMissileSprite1.position.y + opposite);
            }
            else  // angle > 3.0f * M_PI_4 || angle <= -3.0f * M_PI_4
            {
                // Shoot left
                adjacent = _playerMissileSprite1.position.x + Margin;
                opposite = tanf(angle) * adjacent;
                destination = CGPointMake(-Margin, _playerMissileSprite1.position.y - opposite);
            }

            float hypotenuse = sqrtf(adjacent*adjacent + opposite*opposite);
            NSTimeInterval duration = hypotenuse / PlayerMissileSpeed;

            SKAction *missileMoveAction = [SKAction moveTo:destination duration:duration];
            SKAction *missileDoneMoveAction = [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^()   {
            _playerMissileSprite1.hidden = YES;
        }];
        SKAction *moveMissileActionWithDone = [SKAction sequence:@[_missileShootSound, missileMoveAction, missileDoneMoveAction]];

        [_playerMissileSprite1 runAction:moveMissileActionWithDone];

        }

else if (_tripleShot) {

        if (CACurrentMediaTime() - _touchTime < 0.3 && _playerMissileSprite1.hidden)
        {
            UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
            CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
            CGPoint diff = CGPointMake(location.x - _touchLocation.x, location.y - _touchLocation.y);
            float diffLength = sqrtf(diff.x*diff.x + diff.y*diff.y);
            if (diffLength > 4.0f)
            {
                float angle = atan2f(diff.y, diff.x);
                _playerMissileSprite1.zRotation = angle - SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.f);

                _playerMissileSprite1.position = _playerSprite.position;
                _playerMissileSprite1.hidden = NO;

                float adjacent, opposite;
                CGPoint destination;

                if (angle <= -M_PI_4 && angle > -3.0f * M_PI_4)
                {
                    // Shoot down
                    angle = M_PI_2 - angle;
                    adjacent = _playerMissileSprite1.position.y + Margin;
                    opposite = tanf(angle) * adjacent;
                    destination = CGPointMake(_playerMissileSprite1.position.x - opposite, -Margin);
                }
                else if (angle > M_PI_4 && angle <= 3.0f * M_PI_4)
                {
                    // Shoot up
                    angle = M_PI_2 - angle;
                    adjacent = _winSize.height - _playerMissileSprite1.position.y + Margin;
                    opposite = tanf(angle) * adjacent;
                    destination = CGPointMake(_playerMissileSprite1.position.x + opposite, _winSize.height + Margin);
                }
                else if (angle <= M_PI_4 && angle > -M_PI_4)
                {
                    // Shoot right
                    adjacent = _winSize.width - _playerMissileSprite1.position.x + Margin;
                    opposite = tanf(angle) * adjacent;
                    destination = CGPointMake(_winSize.width + Margin, _playerMissileSprite1.position.y + opposite);
                }
                else  // angle > 3.0f * M_PI_4 || angle <= -3.0f * M_PI_4
                {
                    // Shoot left
                    adjacent = _playerMissileSprite1.position.x + Margin;
                    opposite = tanf(angle) * adjacent;
                    destination = CGPointMake(-Margin, _playerMissileSprite1.position.y - opposite);
                }

                float hypotenuse = sqrtf(adjacent*adjacent + opposite*opposite);
                NSTimeInterval duration = hypotenuse / PlayerMissileSpeed;

                SKAction *missileMoveAction = [SKAction moveTo:destination duration:duration];
                SKAction *missileDoneMoveAction = [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^() {
                    _playerMissileSprite1.hidden = YES;
                }];
                SKAction *moveMissileActionWithDone = [SKAction sequence:@[_missileShootSound, missileMoveAction, missileDoneMoveAction]];

                [_playerMissileSprite1 runAction:moveMissileActionWithDone];
```

Comment: When you get four levels of if/else statement deep it is well past tie to refactor some of those into helper methods. Then it will be much easier to understand. 120+ lines in a single method is also generally an indication there are to many things going on, many developers feel that 10 lines are on the large size. Also the end of the method is missing.

Comment: If your talking about the multiple missing "}" I left those out intentionally.  The code runs fine but does not fire anything when I select "_tripleShot".  I'm not sure how I could condense the methods, maybe add a method for each direction and then call those in the touchesEnded method, but I am still relatively new to coding, and just trying to mix up what I am learning from websites and also trying to expand on that to ideas that I develop throughout the day.

Comment: Take portions of the code and move them to new methods. Name the methods very well and it all becomes very easy to read and clear. Look for information on refactoring code. Personally I like Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin's Clean Code, both the book and the videos. Also NSScreencast by Ben Scheirman has good videos that use small single responsibility methods.

Comment: My problem with this is the variables.  Each of the different "sections" where the touches are recorded are using the touch and location variables declared in the touchesEnded method.  When I tried creating a new method called shootDown the variables are not working with the variables declared in touchesEnded and it's making the program non functioning.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out why the else if (_tripleShot) statement is not working, thank you for pointing me in the direction and authors of gentlemen who can help me make "cleaner" looking code, although I don't think it's too complicated or messy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With five levels of if statements it is easy to get lost.

In this case the first `if (_regularShot)` is all or nothing, probably you want it to match with the `else if (_tripleShot)`. Instead it is matching with `if (diffLength > 4.0f)`.

Hint: To see the levels better, select the entire method and hit control-i, that will re-indent the entire method. Also double clicking on a curly brace will select the code to the matching curly brace, this helps to see indent matches.

Here is a simplified version of your code to make it easier to see what is going on:

```
if (_regularShot) {
    if (CACurrentMediaTime() - _touchTime < 0.3 && _playerMissileSprite1.hidden) {
        ...
        if (diffLength > 4.0f) {
        }
        else if (_tripleShot) {
        }
    }
}
```

The `_tripleShot` code only executes if `_regularShot` is true and two other conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks, I see what your saying about the else if is still being checked in the first if(_regularShot).  I rearranged some of the "}" and it is working great now!  Now if I can figure out how to get it to shoot three of the missiles...agh!